# Images appear in the header on all pages, but not category.php

Tags: categories, custom-header

**EDIT:** I've narrowed this down to the `img` tags within `a` tags getting stripped out at some point. They show up in the Page Source, but not in inspect element.

I've added a custom category.php, and my images aren't working despite being called in the header.php file. They work in index.php, archives templates, etc.

My code for my category.php is the same as index.php, except I add the category to the WP query.

header.php starting at the body tag:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <?php
    $options = get_option( 'magazine_options' );
    $cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
    $cat_name = get_cat_name($cat_id);
    if(($cat_name !== $options['magazine_field_current_issue']) && $cat_name !== ''): ?>
        <div class="banner">
            <p>
                Archived Issue: <?php echo $cat_name; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<div id="content" class="site-content">

<div class="navigation">
    <div class="logo">
        <?php
            $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );
            echo '<a href="'.  get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '"><img src="' . $image[0] . '" / /></a>';
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-only">
        <a href="" class="mobile-menu"><div class="icon-mobile-menu"></div></a>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'container_class' => 'header-mobile-menu' ) ); ?>
    </div>

<?php
    if ( has_nav_menu( 'social' ) ) : ?>
        <nav class="social-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php _e( 'Footer Social Links Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?>">
            <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'social',
                    'menu_class'     => 'social-links-menu',
                    'depth'          => 1,
                    'link_before'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">',
                    'link_after'     => '</span>' . twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'chain' ) ),
                ) );
            ?>
            <?php echo do_shortcode('[Wow-Modal-Windows id=1]');?>
        </nav><!-- .social-navigation -->

    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="search desktop-only">
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'container_class' => 'header-menu desktop-only' ) ); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

category.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
      <?php
        $cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'cover-story', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'cat' => $cat_id );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <?php
        $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID);
        $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id, 'full' );
        $img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $attachment_id, 'full' );
        ?>
        <img class="featured-story tablet-only" src="<?php echo esc_url( $img_src ); ?>"
         srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $img_srcset ); ?>"
         sizes="(max-width: 50em) 87vw, 680px">
         <img class="featured-story mobile-only" src="<?php echo esc_url( $img_src ); ?>"
          srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $img_srcset ); ?>"
          sizes="(max-width: 50em) 87vw, 680px">
        <div class="cover-story-text mobile-only">
          <p>
            Cover Story
          </p>
          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
        </div>
      <div class="featured-story desktop-only" style="background: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>);">
          <div class="cover-story-text">
            <p>
              Cover Story
            </p>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>


            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
          </div>
      </div>

      <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </main><!-- .site-main -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Edit: The admin bar also has a lack of SVGs... This is so odd. [image: WP Admin Bar missing icons]

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, it is going to be very hard helping you without seeing some code... Could you show us the custom.php source code, where you modify the WP_Query object and the header.php file so we can see how those images are inserted in the page?

Comment: I've added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning!

So this sounds like unbalanced html tags...

And indeed, if I concatenate your header file with your category.php file, there are a few closing  and a closing  tags at the end that don't seem to belong there...

I'd suggest a good tag cleanup: make sure everything you open is closed, and you don't have any orphaned closing tags.

Also, but I doubt this relates to your problem here, your logo in the header.php file has an extra backslash:

```
echo '<a href="'.  get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '"><img src="' . $image[0] . '" / /></a>';
```

It should be

```
echo '<a href="'.  get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '"><img src="' . $image[0] . '" /></a>';
```

**UPDATE**

Wait, ok, so you added the whole loop at the top for cover-story posts? If that's the case, then you want to call [wp_reset_postdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after your loop, otherwise you have affected the normal page's current, main loop. You should also check and only reset the loop if you actually had posts to show. Changing that top part, then, it becomes: (new lines indicated)

```
<?php
    $cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'cover-story', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'cat' => $cat_id );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) { // <-------------
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID);
            $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id, 'full' );
            $img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $attachment_id, 'full' );
?>
<img class="featured-story tablet-only" src="<?php echo esc_url( $img_src ); ?>"
    srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $img_srcset ); ?>"
    sizes="(max-width: 50em) 87vw, 680px">
<img class="featured-story mobile-only" src="<?php echo esc_url( $img_src ); ?>"
    srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $img_srcset ); ?>"
    sizes="(max-width: 50em) 87vw, 680px">
<div class="cover-story-text mobile-only">
    <p>
    Cover Story
    </p>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
</div>
<div class="featured-story desktop-only" style="background: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>);">
    <div class="cover-story-text">
        <p>
          Cover Story
        </p>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); // <-------------
    endif; // <-------------
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Updated all of my tags, No luck. My index.php file works and they are the same code except for the added category to the wp query. I also updated that image tag, but that did nothing. Thanks for your help. I'm going to keep digging.

Comment: Just noticed something - I've updated my answer...

Comment: That's still not it. This is such a weird bug.

Comment: Hmmm - indeed it is. And `$cat_id` is set to a valid category ID?

Comment: Yup. When I write it to the error log it prints the correct id.

Comment: Ok - and `$loop->have_posts()` is true? Maybe you're not finding any images for this particular category?

Comment: Yes, it's returning true. These images shouldn't have anything to do with the Category, because they're in the header.php file.

Comment: There are also no php errors being printed.

Comment: All right, so let's back up a bit. Which image exactly does not show up? Could we get a public URL to see the generated page?

Comment: The custom logo, and the SVG's in the Social menu and what is not showing up, and no, I do not have a public link.

Comment: And the *only* difference between the category.php page and the index.php page (for instance) are the 2 lines `$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');` and 
`$args = array( 'post_type' => 'cover-story', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'cat' => $cat_id );` ?

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the link_before and link_after in my social navigation aren't injecting the span tags in. As well as when an anchor tag is around the image the image disappears.

Comment: Just on this one page? It sounds like maybe another plugin might be taking over... Have you tried disabling plugins one by one?

Comment: Yeah, that didn't seem to work. I just created a second header with custom code to make it look right. Thanks for all the help.